# Join multiple tables using MergeJoin programatically using ssis in C#

Tags: ssis

Any idea how to join multiple tables in ssis programatically using Merge Join ? I'm using c#.

thanks,
Jibin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would caution you in using the merge join as far as it can cause performance issues. If you are pulling data from the save server, I would recommend joining the data in your proc or inline sql. If your particular case is that you have heterogeneous data sources(excel, Oracle, etc.) or data on different sources, then all you need to do to use the merge join is drag your data flow buffer outputs from your data sources to your merge join component. After a little configuration, which is explained here http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1322, you then are done. Note- Dont forget that your data has to be sorted before you can use the merge join.